# Should I use a foreign key or string value from foreign table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Lets say you have an employee table and a jobs list table. Each employee must have one job in the table. Normally I would give each job an id and reference it as a foreign key in the employee table. One of my collegues however has suggested that we use the jobs list table as a dictionary and that before inserting / updating we check the 'job type' is present in the table and then insert the job type as a string into the employee table.

As far as I can see

**the Pros:**

> Faster selects (although a join on a primary key should make marginal
>   difference)

**the Cons:**

> Slower to select employees by job type
>    More difficult to change a job
>   type

Which of the above approaches is best?

Comment: No, there is nothing you missed. Is there a question you wanted to ask about the above statements? If not, this should be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Please update your question so that you are actually asking a question. There is however no correct answer for all cases.

Comment: The best practice is to use surrogate PK

Comment: @meagar: You haven't read the question, have you? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I *have* read the post. "Is there anything I missed?" is the only question. This is a website about asking questions. Soliciting critiques does not constitute asking a question.

Comment: @meagar: yes, but I commented your "use additional table/PK" comment, which you have already removed

Comment: Please choose an `Accepted Answer`.  Don't want to rob @Larry for that great answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand why there's a conflict.  You are aware that keys, both primary and foreign, can as easily be string types as number types?  You can have the advantages of both systems by making the job type field the primary key in the job types table and the foreign key in the employee table.

The advantage to this approach is that you don't need to join the job type table back to the employee table to get a descriptive name for the job type, while you still use the database to provide the referential integrity that is important to your database design.

The disadvantage is that if you have a very large number of employees you'll use a bit more storage resources and that if you change the job description you'll need to cascade the changes through the employee table.

While it is common to use integers as primary keys (and some frameworks require it), there's no rule that says it has to be that way.

Answer (score 1):

If it will make it more difficult to administer the job types (which I'm assuming is something you or someone else will be doing), would it really be worth it for a small performance increase?  It also sounds like it might be overly complicating things for a small reward.  I'd say the best practice is to stick with a foreign key for simplicity's sake.